# Selecting the row which has the latest datetime for a specific year

Tags: mysql, sql

Say that there is a MySQL table which has a column with data type `datetime` and there are many rows with year 2015,2016,2017... at this column.

The problem is that i want to write a query that finds the row with highest(newest) datetime column for a specific year. For example i want the query to find the row of highest datetime value for 2015. (I assumed that 31 December is higher than 30 December).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.datetimecol = (select max(t2.datetimecol)
                       from t t2
                       where year(t2.datetimecol) = year(t.datetimecol)
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(mydate) 
FROM mytable
WHERE YEAR(mydate) = 2017
```

or

```
SELECT YEAR(mydate), MAX(mydate)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY YEAR(mydate)
```

Comment: Your query will return the most recent date for each year, not the most recent data.

Comment: The question was how to find the highest date for a specifc year, which is what my query does.

Comment: Really??  Here is the questions: The problem is that i want to write a query that finds the **row with highest(newest) datetime column*** for a specific year. Not the most recent date, @GordonLinoff's solution is the answer.

Comment: Oh... you're right. I understand the question now :)